# Connecting IBM mobile app builder to Cloudant JSON data - bluemix-mobile-services

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-mobile-services

I am using the IBM Bluemix Mobile App Builder tool and understand that it is currently experimental, but I have been having problems connecting the tool to an existing JSON data source. I have tried connecting to the Cloudant instance within Bluemix, but can't find a way to bind the App Builder tool to the Cloudant DB within Bluemix. I see "Mobile App Builder-6v is not currently authorized to access other service instances. I also tried using the credentials inside Bluemix to get to the JSON data, but I get "We couldn't connect to your Cloudant. Please check your Cloudant configuration."

I have also tried using the same Data Source on cloudant.com using the API for the JSON file and my cloudant.com credentials, but I get "We couldn't connect to Cloudant. Please review the entered configuration."

Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Cloudant data source in this format:

`*****************-bluemix.cloudant.com/dbname/`

without the `_all_docs`.

After I removed the `_all_docs` from the URL, I was able to connect to my data source.

For example, here is my configuration for connecting to a database I have called `products`.

[image]