# IBM mobile app builder does not see documents in Cloudant database, why?

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-mobile-services

I followed the steps in this link [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039334/connecting-ibm-mobile-app-builder-to-cloudant-json-data-bluemix-mobile-service) and it worked for the connection to the cloudant database.

[image]

But the "**Mobile App Builder**" says: there are no documents, but there are over 2000 documents.

What is wrong with my configuration?

Regards,

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile App Builder does not support nested objects at the time. The documents in your database contain one nested object.

At this time, you could put all the fields in the first level of JSON (date, time, image, etc.), and it should work.

Mobile App Builder is still experimental, so expect improvements in the future.